# How to dynamically compose a route in angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Let's suppose I have a service that fetches an array of paths formatted in json like this:

```
[{
    "path": "routeName"
    "component": "MyComponent"
}]
```

Of coures "MyComponent" is retrieved as a string. Now I want translate this array into Routes for a routing-module. How can I convert "MyComponent" into the class MyComponent?

The purpose of this is to make my frontend unaware of what it is. To add new routes and components I just need to add a new entry to the file on the server and make it match the component name I create inside the angular app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is app module

```
export const routes: Route[] = [

];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ErrorHandleComponent,
    FilterComponent,
    CreateComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    // AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    CreateComponent,
    FilterComponent,
    ErrorHandleComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now make sure that you have the key value pair obj that returns component against key like:

```
import { CreateComponent } from '../create/create.component';
import { FilterComponent } from '../filter/filter.component';
import { ErrorHandleComponent } from '../error-handle/error-handle.component';

export const components = {
    'CreateComponent': CreateComponent,
    'FilterComponent': FilterComponent,
    'ErrorHandleComponent': ErrorHandleComponent,
};
```

Then put this code in app.component.ts file

```
  constructor(private api: ApiService, private router: Router) {

  }
  getRoute() {
    this.api.get_route().subscribe(res => {
      res.forEach(element => {
         // components key value pair obj
         element.component = components[element.component]; 
        routes.push(element);
      });
      this.rlist = routes;
      this.router.resetConfig(routes);
    });
```

Comment: That's really interesting, but what if I have this thing in a submodule and not in the AppModule. How could I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Inject router into the app module

Step 2: You could change `router.config` whatever you want

```
@
NgModule({
declarations: [
  HomeComponent
  ...
],
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
    ])
],
providers: []})


export class AppModule {
constructor(router: Router) {
    router.config.unshift({ path: 'new_path', component: NewComponent });
}}
```

Comment: Probably I didn't explain correctly. Referring to your code HomeComponent or NewComponent are Type<any> but in my case I get the strings "HomeComponent" and "NewComponent" and I want to retrieve the Type<any> from those strings.

Something like:
const routes = buildPaths(pathNames, componentNames);

...

imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]

where buildPaths(paths: string[], components: string[]): Route[]

Comment: Yup. Similar to statworks answers. After getting your json, map the result from string to component. Then change it in router.config. You could do this in any component or sub modules

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROUTES InjectionToken and instead of passing routes directly in the forRoot/forChild function of the RouterModule, just pass an empty array and instead provide the ROUTES token in the providers section. In that case the Angular router will automatically use the routes from the provided token.

For example,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forChild([])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ROUTES,
      useFactory: (appSettings: AppSettings) => {
        const defaultTab: string = appSettings.APP_VERSION === APP_VERSIONS.NL ? 'tab1' : 'tab2';
        const routes: Routes = [
          {
            path: '',
            component: TabsPage,
            children: [
             ...
            ]
          },
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: defaultTab,
            pathMatch: 'full'
          }
        ];
        return routes;
      },
      deps: [
        APP_SETTINGS
      ],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```